# what does `" mean in a sv macro

Tags: system-verilog

I see the following code in uvm-1.2/macros/uvm_object_defines.svh (line 1409):

```
 __m_uvm_status_container.scope.set_arg_element(`"ARG`",i);
```

what does the `"ARG`" mean in this line? (This code has been downloaded from accellera.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It allows you to expand macro arguments into strings. You can search the [IEEE 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) LRM for `" and immediately get a full answer to your question.